# Why I got an error in my gitlab CI with Pip which is not found?

Tags: python, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to use gitlab CI for the first time. I just want to test (not to deploy) a Python program on it. I don't know why but it failed on pip, which is not found...

Here is the error message of gitlab :

```
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
/bin/bash: line 71: pip: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

And here my .gitlab-ci.yaml:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

myJob:
  stage: build
  image: python:3.6
  script:
    - apt-get update -q -y
    - apt-get install -y python-pip
    - python -V
    - echo "hello world"
    - pip install -r requirements.txt

myJob2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - python test.py
```

Neither the hello world nor the Python version is printed. So I probably made a basic mistake, but which one?

Comment: Your .gitlab-ci.yaml file seems fine that should work. But in your error message in console out, after  Skipping Git submodules setup it has directly gone to last command ( pip install -r requirements.txt ). So your other 4 commands have been skipped. So there will be no pip. What is your gitlab runner version?

Answer (score 14):

Different jobs in your pipeline are run in different containers. To be precise, they run in the container that you specify as `image`. The job `myJob` runs inside a `python:3.6` container, so you have the `pip` command and everything works fine.

For your second job (`myJob2`), you did not specify any image, so the default image will be used, which will likely not be a python image.

Even if your second job was running inside a `python` container, it would still fail because of missing dependencies. You are installing the dependencies in the first job, but you did not specify any artifacts that should be passed to the next job. For more information on passing these artifacts check the [Gitlab CI reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts).

The following `.gitlab-ci.yml` should work:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

myJob:
  stage: build
  image: python:3.6
  script:
    - apt-get update -q -y
    - apt-get install -y python-pip
    - python -V
    - echo "hello world"
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
  artifacts:
    untracked: true

myJob2:
  stage: test
  image: python:3.6
  script:
    - python test.py
```

Comment: `image: python:3.9`


adding this worked for me, thanks